# Genymotion is too slow on browsing websites and running cordova app

Tags: android, cordova, android-emulator, genymotion, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm using mac osx Yosemite and I installed oracle virtual box and Genymotion android emulator. Genemotion runs fine with any pre-installed native apps and they are running fast. However, If I browse websites in the internet browser or run cordova hybrid app. They run too slow so that I can't even able to navigate properly. It happens even when I'm just browsing simple websites. (like google search). Is there anyone with similar issues and have any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

I run Genymotion on my Mac OS. I experienced the same laggy brwosing experience too. Then I tried installing **Opera for android**. To my surprise,it **worked**! The browser seems very fast and clean. Give it a try.